If $x$ is the number of the students who are interested in both sports in this example, what is the minimum value of $x$?
There are $31$ students in a certain class. $19$ of the students are interested in soccer and $14$ of the students are interested in volleyball. If $x$ is the number of the students who are interested in both sports, what is the minimum value of $x$?
This is the answer, but I can't understand where $x<14$ comes from.
$$19 - x + x + 14 - x \leq 31 \implies 2 \leq x$$
$$x \leq 14 \implies 2 \leq x \leq 14 \implies \text{at least} \, 2 \, \text{people}.$$

Can there be more people interested in both sports than there are people interested in volleyball?

Actually. It can be solved by van-diagram

I figured out the answer, 14 is the maximum number that x can be in regard to the van diagram

Let $A,B$ the sets of students interested in soccer and volleyball, respectively. Given $|A|=19$ and $|B|=14$. Let $x$ the number of the students who are interested in both sports (i.e. $|A\cap B|$). From the inclusion–exclusion principle, we get
$$
|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B| = 19 + 14 - x = 33-x. 
$$
However, we know that
$$
|A\cup B| \leq 31 \implies 33-x \leq 31.
$$
From the above inequality, we get $x \geq 2$ which is bounded from below by 2; hence, the minimum is 2.
